# Failing to establish an SSH tunnel in Python (without Putty)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm attempting to automate the process of connecting to a Redshift server using Python without relying on PuTTY. Currently, I'm on a Windows machine, and I need to extract data from PostgreSQL on a Redshift server. However, to achieve this, I have to:

1. Open the PuTTY .exe
2. Enter this command in PuTTY: `"Putty -P <port_number> -noagent -N -L 5534:<redshift_host>:5534 <username>@<remote_host> -i <private_key_file> -pw <password>"`
3. Wait a few seconds until PuTTY shows the tunnel is open
4. Open my Jupyter Python Notebook and finally execute my query:

   cxn= psycopg2.connect(user="sql_username",
   password="sql_password",
   host="host_ip",
   port=5534,
   database="database_name")

Extract the data and store it as a dataframe.
Since this is quite a manual and not so efficient process, I have been searching the web to stop using PuTTY altogether and find a new way to create the tunnel and extract my data. I have even converted my .ppk key to a .pem format to use with other libraries. I'm using paramiko and SSHTunnelForwarder, but I have not been successful in actually connecting correctly to my tunnel. Here is my code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder


ssh_host = <remote_host>
ssh_port = <port_number>
ssh_user = <username>
ssh_key_path = 'ssh_key_redshift.pem'  
ssh_password = <password>

redshift_host = <redshift_host>
redshift_port = 5534
redshift_user = <username>


# Create an SSH tunnel
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (ssh_host, ssh_port),
    ssh_username=ssh_user,
    ssh_pkey=ssh_key_path,
    ssh_password=ssh_password,
    remote_bind_address=(redshift_host, redshift_port),
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 5534)
) as tunnel:
    print("SSH Tunnel established successfully.")
    input("Press Enter to close the tunnel...")
```

But unfortunately is not working to open and connect the tunnel and when I use shhtunnel.

I have heard of the paramiko library, and I would be thrilled if anyone could assist me with this. Essentially, what I need to do is establish an SSH tunnel using `<port_number>`, binding the local port 5534 to a Redshift host's port 5534, using the credentials and the key file that I have converted to .pem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know redshift, but adapted to what I do for postgres or mariadb :

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import redshift_connector


ssh_host = <remote_host>
ssh_port = <port_number>
ssh_user = <username>
ssh_key_path = 'ssh_key_redshift.pem'  
ssh_password = <password>

redshift_host = <redshift_host> # localhost
redshift_port = 5534 # ! default redshift port is 5539 !
redshift_user = <username>


# Create an SSH tunnel
with SSHTunnelForwarder (
    ssh_address_or_host=ssh_host,
    ssh_port=ssh_port,
    ssh_username=ssh_user,
    ssh_pkey=ssh_key_path,
    ssh_private_key_password=ssh_password,
    remote_bind_address=(redshift_host, redshift_port)
) as tunnel:
    print("SSH Tunnel established successfully.")


    with redshift_connector.connect(
        host=redshift_host,
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        user=redshift_user,
        # database=?
     ) as conn:
        
        # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point you should try to test your second pkey (the *.pem one) without python.

Assuming you are on Windows and hopping you have the ssh tool installed, open PowerShell or cmd and try to run :

```
ssh -i ssh_key_path -L localhost:5534:redshift_host:5534 ssh_user@ssh_host -p ssh_port
```